# Is there such a thing as a multimeter with needle prongs as small as an exacto knife tip?

Tags: current-measurement, surface-mount, multimeter

im working with repairing cell phones and I need to test connectivity, but the multi-meters that i have too big of a tip. are there micro tip multi-meters for precision use on tiny chips as small as 1mm-3mm?

Comment: Get a magnifying glass.

Comment: Most multimeters will take a variety of different test leads with 4mm "banana plugs" or similar (sometimes shrouded) plugs. So you can look for different type "test leads" separately... e.g. http://uk.farnell.com/hirschmann-testmeasurement/932793001/test-lead-kit/dp/1011429?MER=bn-me-ca-r3-reco-all-1

Comment: check out the probes from EZ hook, I've used them and like them personally http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?FV=fff40023,fff80405,fffc01cd&chp=0

Comment: http://www.dipmicro.com/store/MM-TWEEZERPROBE

Comment: Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic in this forum.  Reference: Help->Tour->Don't ask about...Shopping or buying recommendations.

Comment: [Pomona Electronics](http://www.pomonaelectronics.com) makes many different precision test probes.  Model 6275, for example.

Comment: http://travisgoodspeed.blogspot.com/2008/05/syringe-logic-probe.html

Answer (score 2):

I have replaced the gross sized meter probe times on some of my meters with short sewing needles. These have the advantage that they are very sharp and very hard steel so they stay sharp a long time.

In my case I found the needles too small diameter for the collet on the end of the probe lead so I tightly wrapped 30awg bare wire around the end of the needle opposite the point. The wrap length was about 0.5 inch. Then with good flux and a hot iron I soldered the wrapped wire in place to increase the overall diameter of the needle body.

One set of probes I prepared like this about 8 years ago still has nice sharp ends.

Answer (score 0):

Fluke has some very sharp probe attachments you can buy, I use them a lot.  If I don't have those I use a pair of alligator clips and my pics (sharp dental tools you use for rework).  They make for very precise sharp little probes.

Answer (score 0):

A dremel or a metal file will make short work of the probe tips. Make them as thin as you need.